# Using Manipulate to make a 3D plot of a function of three variables

Tags: manipulate

I have a function $S = S(\alpha,\tau,q)$. I am interested in plotting a 3DPlot of $S(q,\tau)$ for a given value of $\alpha$. However, I would like to visualize this by manipulating $\alpha$ with the Manipulate command in Mathematica.

I can't really figure out how to paste the Mathematica code that I am currently trying but one thing I should note is that the range of values for plotting also depends on the variable being manipulated.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: See the docs for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html#28962), first example under "Generalizations and Extensions."

Answer (score 2):

```
myS[x_, y_, a_] := Sin[x y + a];
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[myS[x, y, a], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
 {a, 0, 5}]
```

Incidentally, as a general rule, avoid using variable or function names that begin with an upper-case letter as these may conflict with internal names used by *Mathematica*.

[image]

Comment: What a coincidence!  The same function in the docs! And not even with the OP's notation.  Cool.